# Creating a warc record with requests.get() response using warcio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, warc

I'm using the `warcio` library to read and write `warc` files.

When trying to write a record of a response object from `requests.get(URL,stream=False)`, `warcio` is writing only HTTP headers to the record but not the payload. However, when stream mode is enabled it works fine.

Is there a way store the payload when stream mode is not enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround but not sure if it's the correct way. Instead of making request object streamable, I've made the payload streamable
`BytesIO(response.text.encode())` and this seems to work.

Comment: This workaround is not streaming; the BytesIO() is initialized with the entire response body.

Comment: correct. Basically, warcio payload is expecting a BytesIO like object. When the request is in stream mode it's automatically taken care otherwise passing `BytesIO(response.content)` object works fine